# ApplicationInsights logs not collected for dapr service invocations

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, minimal-apis, azure-container-apps, dapr

I have two .NET applications hosted on Azure Container Apps. Both applications are set up with the same ApplicationInsights instrumentation key, and I include the service when configuring them.

When I make requests to the applications from an external source, I can see the logs for both apps (Information level and above). However, when I perform a service-to-service invocation using Dapr, I do not receive the logs, even if there are errors.

```cs
var methodRequest = this.daprClient.CreateInvokeMethodRequest(HttpMethod.Get,"appid", $"myendpoint");
var response = await this.daprClient.InvokeMethodAsync<ResultBody>(methodRequest, cancellationToken);
```

This is what I can see in ApplicationInsights:

[image: ApplicationInsights trace]

The invoked endpoint is a minimal API and I'm using the `ILoggerFactory` to generate get a logger:

```cs
app.MapGet("/myendpoint", async ([FromServices] ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, /*other parameters*/) =>
{
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("MyEndpoint");
    logger.LogInformation("Logging method here");
    try
    {
```

How can I show all the logs from the invoked endpoint?

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` and complete code file.

Comment: Also share your `Configuration` file.